# Email Content Guided send using Salesforce Campaign is not sending an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We are using salesforce campaigns to send email to the contacts added to the campaign. When we go into Email->Content selected a email with Guided send and selecting the campaign for which email needs to be send.

The email is not sent out and guides send status is failed. We upgrade V5 connector from v2(for which it used to work fine) is there any configuration i might missed or need to make sure it was there. I followed the steps from [a Marketing Cloud Example](https://help.marketingcloud.com/cs-CZ/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/).

> Guided send status under salesforce send
>   Id Status Created Scheduled SyncId JobId
>
> 4084 Failed 2/27/2017 1:33 PM 2/27/2017 1:33 PM 7980

Comment: Try using the Salesforce Send activity under the interactions tab.  And insure your SFMC account is integrated with Salesforce ORG.

Comment: We resolved the issue the email content is taking the default send classification. Which has footer and header set to none. Once we updated the profile footer/header to default it started working fine